# Ambari repository on CentOS 7

Tags: ambari

We are trying to install Ambari server following the manual [Install Ambari 2.2.1 from Public Repositories](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Install+Ambari+2.2.1+from+Public+Repositories).

When we tried to install the Ambari server with the command `yum install ambari-server` it returns that it is nothing to do.

The `ambari.repo` is:

```
#VERSION_NUMBER=2.2.1.0-161

[Updates-ambari-2.2.1.0]
name=ambari-2.2.1.0 - Updates
baseurl=http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos7/2.x/updates/2.2.1.0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos7/RPM-GPG-KEY/RPM-GPG-KEY-Jenkins
enabled=1
priority=1
```

Someone can help us?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the OS installed was of 32 bits and it is obligatory install the 64 bits OS.

Comment: well, sorry off-course, but install hadoop on x32 bit environment o_O?

Answer (score 0):

Just clear the yum cache and then try again it will be solved your problem.

```
yum clean all
yum install ambari-server
```

Note: Make sure you kept the **ambari.repo** file in **/etc/yum.repos.d/** location

Answer (score 0):

This happens in case:

1. Package (`ambari-server`) is already installed
2. Repolist can't find the package (`ambari-server`).

First run `yum list all` if it's not listing package then run

`yum clean all`

Again run `yum list all`
If it's not listing your package you need to add `.repo` file for the same in `/etc/yum.repos.d`